# ¿Cómo programar una placa ESP32 para subir datos a Prometheus?

Tags: arduino

Tengo una ESP32 recogiendo datos de varios sensores (humedad, etc) y me gustaría que fuera subiendo los datos a la nube. Me han recomendado que utilice Prometheus y Grafana, pero no sé por dónde tengo que empezar para conseguir que suba los datos.

Agradecería que alguien me echara una mano, gracias.

Comment: Es [Grafana](https://grafana.com/), y sirve para visualizar los datos almacenados, por ejemplo, en [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/). ¿Hasta dónde has probado? ¿Qué has mirado o quién te ha recomendado esa solución? Deberías comenzar documentándote sobre el funcionamiento de cada herramienta y, en particular, de [cómo enviar datos del exterior a Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! ASi como esta la pregunta se considera demasiada amplia.. podrias aclarar que intentaste hasta ahora y donde tuviste problemas?

Comment: Por cierto, te doy la bienvenida a la comunidad. Te recomiendo que realices el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y que luego consultes el artículo [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sandra. Tu pregunta ha sido cerrada por no proporcionar más información acerca de lo que quieres hacer. Por favor, explica con detalle cómo tienes ahora funcionando tu ESP32, cómo obtienes los datos de los sensores dónde los envías en la actualidad y qué quieres hacer con esos datos (poder consultar histórico de evolución de humedad, por ejemplo). También vendría muy bien que compartieras algo de código o estructura de lo que tienes ya en marcha. Cuanto más información nos proporciones, menos genérica será la respuesta y la pregunta podrá ser reabierta.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder enviar datos a Prometheus desde el exterior debes habilitar el [Pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway), permitiéndote recoger métricas a través de un sencillo [API REST](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/blob/master/README.md#url) con la siguiente estructura de URL:

```
<ESQUEMA>://<DNS/IP>:<PUERTO>/metrics/job/<JOB_NAME>{/<LABEL_NAME>/<LABEL_VALUE>}
```

Basándome en el ejemplo más sencillo de un [cliente HTTP](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpClient/BasicHttpClient.ino) de ESP32, puedo indicarte cómo enviar un valor `50` a la etiqueta [`LABEL_NAME`](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#metric-names-and-labels) (métricas o series temporales de datos) del job [`JOB_NAME`](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/) en cada iteración del `loop()` del ESP32 usando el método `GET`:

```
#include <HTTPClient.h>

void loop() {
  if((wifiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {
    HTTPClient http;
    http.begin("http://URL_PROMETHEUS:PUERTO/metrics/job/JOB_NAME/LABEL_NAME/50");
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    /* ... */
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

También puedes usar el [método POST](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/blob/master/README.md#post-method), pero la estructura de los datos que debes enviar [son mucho más complejos](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZjyKiKxZV83VI9ZKAXRGKaUKK2BIWCT7oiGBKDBpjEY/edit?usp=sharing).